# windows update or search bar version reverts to older date a few minutes after windows loads

Tags: virus

Windows 10 starts seemingly normally. While the OS is loading, on occasions where the pc loads slower, I can see what I believe is an update version in the search bar (next to the windows key - see pic)

At first, it is what seems to be a correct up to date version. Soon after, the update version will change to a version dated for March 30, 2022.  (see attached pictures)

Is this a virus of some sort reverting my windows to a version with a vulnerability that it is dependent on?  I've seen this happen a few times. Most time the searc box loads with visual content already in the window so I'm unable to see the version.   I also found beefexploit on my router (not using the router anymore) but this pc was on the network at the time.  I've since factory reset multiple times, ran virus scans, trying to monitor processes with sysinternals.

Is this some type of persistent rootkit or something?  Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

[image: Up to date version]
[image: reverting to March 30,2022 update]

Answer (score 0):

> I've since factory reset multiple times.  Is this some type of persistent rootkit or something?

Certainly could be.  Try Kaspersky TDSSKiller to see  .

[TDSS Killer](https://support.kaspersky.com/5350)

The only virus that can survive a complete reset is a rootkit virus in my experience.

After you run TDSS Killer, make sure you do a fresh install: Delete ALL partitions, format, and then install Windows 10 . It will create the 3 partitions needed (UEFI, DATA, and Recovery).